# Array filter not working when ng serve/build --prod Angular 7 app

Tags: angular, typescript, production

I have very strange issue with Angular CLI 7 application where all works correctly when running "ng serve". But when running "ng serve --prod". I'm not getting any error while serving or building app. Exact problem is with array.filter(x => x.id === myVariable)

I have tried to run app with --aot=false, --build-optimizer=false, nothing seems to help and whenever prod flag is added to serve or build array.filter is not working.

Here's environment details:

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.4
Node: 8.10.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.10.4
@angular-devkit/core         7.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.0.4
@schematics/angular          7.0.4
@schematics/update           0.10.4
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.1.3
```

angular.json:

```
"configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": false,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            }
          ]
        },
```

Here's the my devil code:

```
searchUser(id: number) {
 const user = this.usersList.filter(x => x.id === id);
 console.log(user);
 return user;
}
```

userList is Array of Json objects like:

```
[
{id: 1, name: "John"},
{id: 2, name: "Mary"},
etc...
]
```

When running app with "ng serve" searchUser returns correct user object and prints user object to console.

When running app with "ng serve --prod" nothing is returned, console log shows just Undefined.

As there is no clear error (during serve or building) I'm out of ideas, why it's not working or should I update some package, etc. I could rewrite that part and not use lambda expression, if that's the issue, but I believe that should work.

thanks!

Comment: How is `userList` getting populated?  Is there an async call to get the list of users from a backend?  Nothing obvious in the code you have posted so far.  Just for testing, see if it all works with a const for `userList` instead of a backend call.

Comment: yes, I make API call from backend, but I can console.log full list out just before filter successfully with running --prod as well. the most mysterious is for me that why I'm not getting any error while running or building

Comment: There is no case `filter` could return undefined. Are you sure you are observing the correct log? I advise to use `console.log({user});` in place of `console.log(user)`, so the output will be more meaningful with a little effort

Comment: Otherwise, if your configuration doesn't support automatic stringify, use `console.log('user', user)`

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1) Before .filter function, please check if usersList have data or not. (May be its a service call and not handled properly).
2) Please define userList as a type of array:

> `usersList: Array<object>;`

Answer (score 0):

This happened probably because at the time the variable was accessed,  `this.usersList` is null, undefined, or a value other than an array. You can cast the value first to an array and be sure that the filter function will be available whenever you need it.

```
<Array>(this.usersList).filter(....)
```

or

```
<Array<object>>(this.usersList).filter(....)
```

Also, you could check for the value of `this.usersList` first

```
let user;
if(Array.isArray(this.usersList)){
   user = this.usersList.filter(....)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, silly mistake I had.

```
searchUser(id: number) {
const user = this.usersList.filter(x => x.id === id);
```

that was old code, with slightly different reason, the not working one was:

```
searchUser(user) {
...
```

where user is an object and user.id which I printed out to console was visible as some number indeed, but the actual type was string. so changed to:

```
const user = this.usersList.filter(x => x.id === +id);
```

that did the trick. Something I will probably now remember for ever, check the variable types! 
Still thanks for thinking along.